# ember.js Ember.Select throws error "Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of undefined"

Tags: ember.js, ember.select

So, I have this code:

```
{{#if isClient}}
    {{view Ember.Select
            value=country
            content=options.country
            prompt='Please select a country'}}
{{/if}}
```

Which works wonderfully at load because `isClient` defaults to true. However, when I set `isCLient` to false, I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of undefined
```

Anyone with a better understanding of the underlying code have any ideas here?

Comment: Are you trying to read a value out of the select menu somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out what the problem was.

I was using the ember-animate library and calling:

```
Ember.View.reopen({
    willAnimateIn: function () {
        this.$().hide();
    },
    animateIn: function (done) {
        this.$().fadeIn(250, done);
    },
    animateOut: function (done) {
        this.$().fadeOut(250, done);
    },
});
```

Since Ember.Select is a view, the animation features were being called when it was supposed to appear and disappear. So, I just changed the above to this:

```
Ember.AnimatedView = Ember.View.extend({
```

And all is well.